# Override callback for particular context menu item

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to add some extra logic for a 'Show all' item in Viewer context menu. Could you suggest some way to override the default logic? I can't find a good one. Maybe replacing the item with my own could be an option, but there is no way to remove default "Show all" in this case (and to put my own "Show all" into the same position in context menu)

Comment: The background logic of the ’Show all’ item is actually calling the ’Viewer3D#ioslate()’, so you can add an event handler of the Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT and catch the case when event.nodeIdArray.length === 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no explicit API exposed to achieve this unfortunately the easiest way would be to operate on the menu item and swap in your own callback the "rogue way":

```
NOP_VIEWER.registerContextMenuCallback('overrideIsolate',(menu,status)=>{
   if(status.hasSelected){
   const isolateButton = menu.children[0]
   const newIsolateButton = isolateButton .cloneNode(true);
   isolateButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newIsolateButton , old_element);
   newIsolateButton.onclick = //...
   }
})
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks, got it. Hope you promise to keep "Show all" item at the first place in the list forever =)